# Linear Interpolation on missing values at the end of the period

Tags: sas, linear-interpolation

Here is a dataset example :

```
data data;
   input group $ date value;
   datalines;
A 2001 1.5
A 2002 2.6
A 2003 2.8
A 2004 2.9
A 2005 .
B 2001 0.1
B 2002 0.6
B 2003 0.7
B 2004 1.4
B 2005 .
C 2001 4.7
C 2002 4.6
C 2003 4.8
C 2004 5.0
C 2005 .
;
run;
```

I want to replace the missing values of the variable "value" for each group using linear interpolation.

I tried using proc expand :

```
proc expand data=data method = join out=want;
    by group;
    id date;
    convert value;
run;
```

But it's not replacing any value in the output database.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three ways to do it. Your missing data is at the end of the series. You are effectively doing a forecast with a few points. `proc expand` isn't good for that, but for the purposes of filling in missing values, these are some of the options available.

**1. PROC EXPAND**

You were close! Your missing data is at the end of the series, which means it has no values to join between. You need to use the `extrapolate` option in this case. If you have missing values between two data points then you do not need to use `extrapolate`.

```
proc expand data=data method = join 
            out=want
            extrapolate;
    by group;
    id date;
    convert value;
run;
```

**2. PROC ESM**

You can do interpolation with exponential smoothing models. I like this method since it can account for things like seasonality, trend, etc.

```
/* Convert Date to SAS date */
data to_sas_date;
    set data;
    year = mdy(1,1,date);

    format year year4.;
run;

proc esm data=to_sas_date
         out=want
         lead=0;
    by group;
    id year interval=year;
    forecast value / replacemissing;
run;
```

**3. PROC TIMESERIES**

This will fill in values using mean/median/first/last/etc. for a timeframe. First convert the year to a SAS date as shown above.

```
proc timeseries data=to_sas_date
                out=want;
    by group;
    id year interval=year;
    var value / setmissing=average;
run;
```

Comment: That's some very detailed answer, thank you very much, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the `expand` procedure, but you can add `extrapolate` to the `proc expand` statement.

```
proc expand data=data method = join out=want extrapolate;
    by group;
    id date;
    convert value;
run;
```

Results in:

```
  Obs    group    date    value

    1      A      2001     1.5
    2      A      2002     2.6
    3      A      2003     2.8
    4      A      2004     2.9
    5      A      2005     3.0
    6      B      2001     0.1
    7      B      2002     0.6
    8      B      2003     0.7
    9      B      2004     1.4
   10      B      2005     2.1
   11      C      2001     4.7
   12      C      2002     4.6
   13      C      2003     4.8
   14      C      2004     5.0
   15      C      2005     5.2
```

Please take note of the statement [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/68148/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_expand_syntax02.htm)

> By default, PROC EXPAND avoids extrapolating values beyond the first or last input value for a series and only interpolates values within the range of the nonmissing input values. Note that the extrapolated values are often not very accurate and for the SPLINE method the EXTRAPOLATE option results may be very unreasonable. The EXTRAPOLATE option is rarely used."

Comment: Damn, how I did not find about extrapolate, thank you very much!